# Justification of steps

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

I'm taking Real Analysis starting in January and I'm getting a head start now so as to make the class somewhat easier.  In the text we are using (Bartle and Sherbert, 4th ed.), it has examples where the student has to justify various steps and the one I am stuck on is justifying how $$\frac{(2x+1)}{(x+2)} - 1$$ becomes $$\frac{(x-1)}{(x+2)}$$

I show that since $x+2$ is nonzero, there is an existing $1/(x+2)$ in the set of real numbers, so I get $$ (x+2) \cdot \frac{1}{x+2} = 1$$ by the existence of reciprocals.

Now the next step (to my understanding) is to show that $-(x+2) = -x-2$.  I am fairly certain that the field axioms won't help, and I have been attempting to find some correlation between this issue and the Order Properties of the set of real numbers, but I stumble upon great difficulty.

I know how to do the last step, but I also feel like I'm overthinking this justification.  So my questions are:

(1) Am I overthinking this? If so, where did I start overthinking?

(2) If I am on the right track, can someone please help me a little bit?

I am new, so forgive me if it sounds like I am pleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $a \times (b+c)= (a \times b)+(a\times c)$ from the field axioms (distributivity of multiplication over addition).

Now let $a=-1, b=x, c=1$.

Alternatively, if $-(x+2)$ is the additive inverse of $x+2$ then with commutativity of addition $0=0+0=-x+x+-2+2=(-x-2)+(x+2)$ so $-(x+2)=(-x-2)$

Comment: I can't believe I did not see that. Thank you very much.